# Rails resources route with IDs with multiple values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest

How do you create a Rails resources route that has more than 1 value for it's ID?

Example:

You have a resource named `widget` and it's ID is 2 strings: "foo" and "bar".

Can you have a URLs like these?

```
Index: http://domain.com/widgets
New: http://domain.com/widgets/new
Create: http://domain.com/widgets
Show: http://domain.com/widgets/foo/bar
Edit: http://domain.com/widgets/foo/bar/edit
Update: http://domain.com/widgets/foo/bar
Destroy: http://domain.com/widgets/foo/bar
```

Or am I stuck making these manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hate to answer my own question. I did find a solution.  In Rails 4 there is a `:param` parameter to resources that you can use to set to many items.

```
resources :widgets, param: 'first_id/:second_id'
```

Notice that the first param does not have a colon, but the other one does. This was the key to getting it to work.

In Rails 2 this parameter was called `:key` and Rails 3 removed it.

Answer (score 2):

```
resources :domains, only: [:index, :new, :create]

get 'widgets/*id', to: 'widgets#show'
get 'widgets/*id/edit', to: 'widgets#edit'
put 'widgets/*id', to: 'widgets#update'
delete 'widgets/*id', to: 'widgets#destroy'
```

you will get params[:id] as 'foo/bar'